# how does a nltk.tree.Tree object generate a string representation of the tree?

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to understand the nltk.tree module. I got confused as to why when an nltk.tree.Tree object is printed, it doesn't print out the address. Instead, it prints out a string representation of the tree.

I have looked at the source code in nltk.tree but I which part of the code formats the tree into a string.

```
import nltk
from nltk.tree import Tree
print(Tree(1, [2, Tree(3, [4]), 5]))
print(type(Tree(1, [2, Tree(3, [4]), 5])))
```

Output

```
(1 2 (3 4) 5)
<class 'nltk.tree.Tree'>
```

If a define an example class

```
class example():
    def __init__(self):
        ''
this_class = example()
print(this_class)
print(type(this_one))
```

Output:

```
<__main__.example object at 0x000001397F255668>
<class '__main__.example'>
```

I get this. Why is that?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Good question! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear, I supposed the question is asking why is it that the input to the `Tree` object in NLTK are integers but when printing, the representation prints out the the string without raising any errors.

Lets dig a little into the code.

The part that prints out the `Tree` in human-readable bracketed parse format is the `__str__()` function at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tree.py#L820

If we take closer look, it calls the `pformat()` function:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self.pformat()
```

The `pformat()` function at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tree.py#L835:

```
def pformat(self, margin=70, indent=0, nodesep='', parens='()', quotes=False):
    """
    :return: A pretty-printed string representation of this tree.
    :rtype: str
    :param margin: The right margin at which to do line-wrapping.
    :type margin: int
    :param indent: The indentation level at which printing
        begins.  This number is used to decide how far to indent
        subsequent lines.
    :type indent: int
    :param nodesep: A string that is used to separate the node
        from the children.  E.g., the default value ``':'`` gives
        trees like ``(S: (NP: I) (VP: (V: saw) (NP: it)))``.
    """

    # Try writing it on one line.
    s = self._pformat_flat(nodesep, parens, quotes)
    if len(s) + indent < margin:
        return s

    # If it doesn't fit on one line, then write it on multi-lines.
    if isinstance(self._label, string_types):
        s = '%s%s%s' % (parens[0], self._label, nodesep)
    else:
        s = '%s%s%s' % (parens[0], unicode_repr(self._label), nodesep)
    for child in self:
        if isinstance(child, Tree):
            s += (
                '\n'
                + ' ' * (indent + 2)
                + child.pformat(margin, indent + 2, nodesep, parens, quotes)
            )
        elif isinstance(child, tuple):
            s += '\n' + ' ' * (indent + 2) + "/".join(child)
        elif isinstance(child, string_types) and not quotes:
            s += '\n' + ' ' * (indent + 2) + '%s' % child
        else:
            s += '\n' + ' ' * (indent + 2) + unicode_repr(child)
    return s + parens[1]
```

**If we look at how the string `s` variable is created in the `pformat` function we see multiple use of `unicode_repr()`.**

**That's where the inputs are converted to string inside the pformat when printing but the child and values in the `Tree` object still remains the same type as they were input.**

Now if we look at `unicode_repr` in `nltk.tree.py`,

```
from nltk.compat import python_2_unicode_compatible, unicode_repr
```

We see it comes from `nltk.compat` from https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/compat.py#L298

```
def unicode_repr(obj):
    """
    For classes that was fixed with @python_2_unicode_compatible
    ``unicode_repr`` returns ``obj.unicode_repr()``; for unicode strings
    the result is returned without "u" letter (to make output the
    same under Python 2.x and Python 3.x); for other variables
    it is the same as ``repr``.
    """
    if PY3:
        return repr(obj)

    # Python 2.x
    if hasattr(obj, 'unicode_repr'):
        return obj.unicode_repr()

    if isinstance(obj, text_type):
        return repr(obj)[1:]  # strip "u" letter from output

    return repr(obj)
```

In Python 3, the `nltk.compat.unicode_repr` simply returns the `repr` that's by default in unicode, specifically `utf8` IIRC.

But in Python 2, it first checks whether the object has a `unicode_repr()` monkey-patch function.

Then it checks it's a type of `text_type` from the `six` library, if so, it'll print out the output without the `u` prefix, e.g. `u"..."`

Finally, it's Python 2 and the object doesn't have a `unicode_repr()` and isn't a `six.text_type`, it'll simply prints out the `repr(obj)`.

So going back to the question, in the case where the the object is an integer, the `repr(int)` will be converted into a string.

```
>>> type(1)
<class 'int'>
>>> repr(1)
'1'
>>> type(repr(1))
<class 'str'>
```